# MatLab: identical function gets two different results

Tags: matlab, function, mat

I see the following behavior in 2013a and 2014a on Windows computers:

Someone sends me a .mat file. In this file, a function fi(th, beta) is defined. On the command line I call fi for two values (actually beta is a matrix). Then, I click "edit value" for fi and don't change anything. Then, when I call fi(th, beta) again I get a completely different value.

How can this be? How can I tell what is the "correct" value?

Comment: How is a function defined in a `.mat` file? Ad does the function do anything to modify the variables? You really haven't given enough information for anyone to give a proper answer, what is in the `.mat` file and what is the `fi` function?

Comment: Sorry David, I will try to provide some more information. fi is defined as an anonymous function I believe:  >> fi  
fi = @(th,beta)D.^2.*beta(:,1).^2.*(1-irf(th,beta)).*(irf(th,beta)-beta(:,3)).^2./(irf(th,beta).*(1-beta(:,3)).^2). irf is another function defined similarly in the .mat file.

Comment: At first I was afraid that because the file sender had named her variable beta, it was calling the function beta, but I believe that this is not the case (because the colon notation forces MatLab to look at the matrix beta and not the function)

Comment: Are you sure you are not talking about an `.m` file? These can be opened in the text editor so you can actually see the code. Post it here (edit your original question) if you find it. Also check if any variable is defined with the word `persistent` in the code, that could give different results after each call.

Comment: It's definitely a .mat file. I cannot open it in a text editor. When I open it in MatLab it imports a bunch of variables into the workspace (including the anonymous function fi). Unfortunately I cannot post the file here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind your issue is that when clicking **edit value** on a function handle, it gets updated. In your function, **D** is used, which was a variable during creation of the function handle. Suppose **D** now has another value, **fi** will use the new value after pressing **edit value**. Let me give you an example:

```
>> k = 2;
>> f = @(x)k*x;
>> f(4)

ans =

     8

>> k = 4;
>> f(4)

ans =

     8
```

In this example, **k** is changed after **f** is defined. However, **f** will have its original definition. When I use **edit value** and don't change anything, it will nevertheless use the new value of **k**.

```
>> f % only to show the function has not changed

f = 

    @(x)k*x

>> f(4)

ans =

    16
```

I hope this clearifies your problem.

Your question regarding the correct value thus depends on the values and function handles used inside the function handle.

Comment: Thank you! It is clear that is what is happening when I look at it after reading your answer. I never would have guessed that the function "caches" the value. The sender of the file must have changed the value of D after editing the function and then sent it to me.